# Need help plotting and finding local maxima and minima in Python using sympy. first part works but can't figure out how to do the other parts

Tags: python, matplotlib, math, plot, sympy

This is the assignment I'm working on [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXWsr.png).

I am asked to use Python with the Sympy package to code it. I was able to get the right ouput for Part A.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linspace, math, arange, linspace
from sympy import *
import sympy as sp
import math

x = Symbol('x')
f = (x**(4/5)) * ((x-4)**2)   
fd = diff(f) #first derivative
fdd = diff(fd) #second derivative (for later)
print("f' =", fd)

print("Critical Vales are:")
dRoots = solve(Eq(fd, 0)) #finds critical values
print(dRoots)
```

I don't know how to code part B and C where it asks for the local maxima and minima and for the plot of `f` on the interval `x ∈ [−1, 6]`.
What I have so far gives me a "'>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'" error

```
fdd_val = solve(Eq(fdd, 0))
if fdd_val > 0:
    print("Local Maxima = ",fdd_val)
if fdd_val < 0:
    print("Local Minima = ",fdd_val)
```

Comment: Note that `fdd_val` is a list of possible values. You could iterate through the list with `for val in fdd_val:` and than do the `if`test with each element of the list.

Comment: Please add the text of the assignment in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, we try to steer clear of posting homework questions on S.O., but since you took a genuine attempt at doing the problem, I'll offer some tips and corrections to your code.

```
from sympy import *
# Optimize imports -> if you don't need it, don't include it

x = Symbol('x')
f = (x**(4/5)) * ((x-4)**2)   
fd = diff(f) #first derivative

# pick more descriptive variable names: you'll thank yourself later. Like 'second_derivative' or even 'sd'
fdd = diff(fd) #second derivative (for later)
print("f' =", fd)

print("Critical Vales are:")

# call solve on fd like the documentation suggests.
dRoots = solve(fd) #finds critical values, returns a list
print(dRoots, '\n')
for root in dRoots:
    # Use function.subs(variable, value) to evaluate d2/dx^2 [f(x)] at each critical point
    fdd_val = fdd.subs(x, root)
    print(f"At root {root:.5g}, second derivative at this point is {fdd_val:.5g} which is "
          f"{'less' if fdd_val < 0 else 'greater'} than zero, so this is a local _____")
```

This revised code should point out the right way to evaluate expressions according to the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/solvers.html), as well as give you some insight on how to proceed. You should be able to finish up from here. Cheers